# Source of LinkedIn script to create embeddable share widget

Tags: javascript, html, widget, linkedin-api

I am looking at the docs here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share

and I have this:

[image]

the problem is that it's referencing a script file:

```
 src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js"
```

**where/how do I get that script file?** I need to include that script file in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script it in where you typed. `platform.linkedin.com/in.js` just remove the `//`. If you are wondering how to download it.

1. open the url `platform.linkedin.com/in.js`.
2. Right click on the code
3. Click on save page as
4. save where you want it